# How to encode XviD using ffmpeg for Home Theater/DVD Player?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, xvid, mpeg4, home-theater

I wanted to convert a file so I can play it my DVD player which only works with divx/xvid. I tried :

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i "in.mp4" -t 480.00 -vf scale=720:301,pad=720:576:0:137 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:1 -b:v 2500K -vcodec libxvid -aspect 1.25 -b:a:0 128K -ac:a:0 2 -ar:a:0 48000 -codec:a:0 libmp3lame "out.avi"
```

I wanted to know what options I should use for the resulting file to also have these characteristics (as close as possible to the "Divx Home Theater" profile):

```
Macroblocks: 40500 bps
VBV Buffer: 384kB
VBV Bitrate: 4854 kbps
B-Frame: 1
```

My `ffmpeg` build info is:

```
ffmpeg version 2.2.git built on Sep 28 2014 08:33:32 with gcc 4.6.2 (GCC)
```

Also my OS is Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FFmpeg wiki has a page about this: [MPEG-4 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MPEG-4).

Long story short:
`ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v mpeg4 -vtag xvid output.avi`

There are, of course, different support levels on different devices. The email exchange about a very limited device [Need code to convert MP4 to DivX AVI](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-September/009422.html)  seems to point at a lower level standard (use it if you can't test the device beforehand):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -sn -c:a libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -c:v libxvid \
    -crf 24 -vtag DIVX -vf scale=640:480 -aspect 4:3 -mbd rd -flags +mv4+aic \
    -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 30 -vb 1500k output.avi
```

Comment: I get a warning when I try to use these options: `Codec AVOption crf (Select the quality for constant quality mode) specified for output file #0 (output.avi) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.`

Comment: is xvid belong to mpeg4?

Answer (score 5):

Personally I use these options:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE -c:v libxvid -q:v 5 -q:a 5 OUTPUT_FILE.avi
```

The point that I would like to stress is that the option -q:v 5 is crucial. This option sets the quality of the video (1 = best, 31 = worse). When this option is omitted, I got a compatible file of poor quality.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I spent a few hours trying to handle issue with FFmpeg, playback, and playback quality. This finally solved it.